# Separate list by first occurence of variable in SWI-Prolog without instantiating the variable itself

Tags: list, prolog, instantiation

I have following source-code:

```
split_list(List, L, [R1|RN], Condition) :-
   find_first(List, R1, Condition),
   append(L, [R1|RN], List), 
   forall(member(X, L),
   not(call(Condition, X))).

find_first([H|_], H, Condition) :- call(Condition, H), !.
find_first([_|T], X, Condition) :- find_first(T, X, Condition).
```

This Prolog program splits a list `List` into two lists `L` and `[R1|RN]`. `R1` is the first element of `List` which satisfies the predicate `Condition`. `L` contains all elements in `List` before `R1`. `L` does not contain any element satisfying `Condition`. `RN` contains all elements which follow `R1` in `List`.

My aim now is to write some predicate, which separates some list `[a,b,c,D,d,f,e,f,d]` into two lists `[a, b, c]` and `[D, d, f, e, f, d]` without instantiating the variable D.

I just tried the call:

```
split_list([a,b,c,_,d,f,e,f,d], L, R, var).
```

but this produces much solutions by instantiating _ by a or b or c and so on. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, this is a more useful `find_first` (with argument order changed to be more [sensible](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/split-list/4836/8)):

```
% P means previous, R means remainder
find_first_succ(Cond, L, P, [H|T]) :-
    find_first_succ_(L, Cond, P, [H|T]).

find_first_succ_([H|T], Cond, [], [H|T]) :-
    call(Cond, H), !.
find_first_succ_([H|T], Cond, [H|P], R) :-
    find_first_succ_(T, Cond, P, R).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- find_first_succ(var, [a,b,c,_,d,f,e,f,d], P, R).
P = [a, b, c],
R = [_, d, f, e, f, d].
```

So, you don't need that problematic `append`.

Answer (score 0):

I found some solution:

```
split_list(List, L, [R1|RN], Condition) :- member(R1, List), append(L, [R1|RN], List), call(Condition, R1).
```